# Trying to check if brackets is balanced or unbalanced

Tags: java, data-structures

Hi there I am working on assignment 1-1 and I'm having a hard time with this assignment When I submit the code below in the assignment with the input = [] it returns output = 0 when it should be returning output = Success. Any idea what I am doing wrong.

The below program should check if the string has `balanced brackets` or not and should return the result.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Stack;

class Bracket {
    Bracket(char type, int position) {
        this.type = type;
        this.position = position;
    }

    boolean Match(char c) {
        if (this.type == '[' && c == ']')
            return true;
        if (this.type == '{' && c == '}')
            return true;
        if (this.type == '(' && c == ')')
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    char type;
    int position;
}

class check_brackets {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader input_stream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input_stream);
        String text = reader.readLine();

        int pos = 0;

        Stack<Bracket> opening_brackets_stack = new Stack<Bracket>();
        for (int position = 0; position < text.length(); ++position) {
            char next = text.charAt(position);

            if (next == '(' || next == '[' || next == '{') {
                // Process opening bracket, write your code here
                Bracket tmp = new Bracket(next, position);

                opening_brackets_stack.push(tmp);
                break;

            }

            if (next == ')' || next == ']' || next == '}') {
                // Process closing bracket, write your code here
                Bracket item = opening_brackets_stack.pop();

                if (!item.Match(next)) {
                    pos = position + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Printing answer, write your code here
        if (pos == 0 && opening_brackets_stack.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Success");
        } else {
            if (pos == 0) {
                while (opening_brackets_stack.size() > 1)
                    opening_brackets_stack.pop();
                pos = opening_brackets_stack.peek().position;
            }
            System.out.println(pos);
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
public class check_brackets {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader input_stream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input_stream);
        String text = reader.readLine();

        Stack<Bracket> opening_brackets_stack = new Stack();
        //traverse the string
        for(int position=0;position<text.length();position++) {
            //Get current char
            char current = text.charAt(position);
            //if the current char is starting bracker,then push it to stack
            if(current=='(' || current=='[' || current=='{') {

                Bracket pos = new Bracket(current,position);

                opening_brackets_stack.push(pos);
            }

            if(current==')' || current==']' || current=='}') {

                Bracket newItem = opening_brackets_stack.pop();

                if(!newItem.Match(current)) {  
                    System.out.println(position+1);
                    return;
                }
            }

        }

        if(opening_brackets_stack.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Success");
        }else {
            Bracket item = opening_brackets_stack.pop();

            System.out.println(item.position+1);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Please format the code so you don't have entire methods on a single line, and fix the indentations.

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the loop at each position instead you need to continue. Also put final check outside for loop,

```
public class check_brackets { public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader input_stream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input_stream);
    String text = reader.readLine();

    int pos = 0;

    Stack<Bracket> opening_brackets_stack = new Stack<Bracket>();
    for (int position = 0; position < text.length(); ++position) {
        char next = text.charAt(position);

        if (next == '(' || next == '[' || next == '{') {
            // Process opening bracket, write your code here
            Bracket tmp = new Bracket(next, position);

            opening_brackets_stack.push(tmp);
            continue;  // continue not break

        }

        if (next == ')' || next == ']' || next == '}') {
            // Process closing bracket, write your code here
            if (opening_brackets_stack.isEmpty()) {  //condition the check if stack is empty
                pos = position + 1;
                break;
            }
            // Process closing bracket, write your code here
            Bracket item = opening_brackets_stack.pop();

            if (!item.Match(next)) {
                pos = position + 1;
                break; 
            }
        }

    }

// Printing answer, write your code here
   if (pos == 0 && opening_brackets_stack.isEmpty())
    System.out.println("Success");
 else
    System.out.println("Failure at position: "+pos);
}
}
```

Better solution:

```
private static boolean checkParenthesisMap(String text) {
    Map<Character, Character> brackets = Map.of('{', '}', '(', ')', '[', ']');
    Stack<Character> bracStack = new Stack<>();
    for (int i=0; i<text.length(); i++){
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        if (brackets.containsKey(c))
            bracStack.push(brackets.get(c));
        else if (bracStack.isEmpty() || bracStack.pop() != c)
            return false;
    }
    return bracStack.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: I tried taking that break away and adding the continue. It is still returning a 0. For instance, this time the input was: '[' and the output showed zero when it should have been 1

Comment: why should it be 1? you don’t even require to check the position in the end. It should either be success or failure, isn’t it?

Comment: I have updated my code and posted it in my question. So it is returning a few things properly. if the input is "{}" then it outputs "Success", if the input is "{" the output is 1 but the only problem is that it is throwing error when the input is "]". It gives me this error `Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException` with these below it `at java.base/java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:101)
 at java.base/java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:83)
 at check_brackets.main(check_brackets.java:47)` any idea why?

Comment: You need to add an empty stack condition in the second for loop. I have updated the answer. Added a concise solution as well. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too

```
static boolean checkEquilibrate(String string) {
    Stack<Character> brackets = new Stack<>();
    boolean equilibrateBrackets = true;
    string = getBrackets(string);

    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        // If string contains '{', '[', or '(' this will be added to the Stack named brackets
        if (string.charAt(i) == '{' || string.charAt(i) == '[' || string.charAt(i) == '(') {
            brackets.push(string.charAt(i));
        // Else if Stack is Empty there´s no reason to execute this part.
        } else if (!brackets.isEmpty()) {
            switch (string.charAt(i)) {
                case ')':
                    if (brackets.peek() == '(') brackets.pop();
                case ']':
                    if (brackets.peek() == '[') brackets.pop();
                case '}':
                    if (brackets.peek() == '{') brackets.pop();
            }
        // Else if Stack is empty and the next char is a "closing brackets" means that that the brackets are not properly placed
        } else if (brackets.isEmpty() && string.charAt(i) == '}' || string.charAt(i) == ']' || string.charAt(i) == ')') {
            equilibrateBrackets = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return equilibrateBrackets;
}
```